# Can't start SonarQube on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, shell, ubuntu, sonarqube

I'm trying to launch SonarQube application and I'm getting some errors. I thought it has to do with memory and thread limits but I reconfigured it and still no results. Here is my output for `./sonar.sh console`:

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2019.08.08 12:24:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp
jvm 1    | 2019.08.08 12:24:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.08.08 12:24:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2019.08.08 12:24:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2019.08.08 12:24:03 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.08.08 12:24:03 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | /bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
jvm 1    | ./bin/elasticsearch: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
jvm 1    | ./bin/elasticsearch: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

About "shell level" error, I echoed `$SHLVL` and its value is 1. Here's my output for `ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 60028
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 60028
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

..and my java version:

```
# java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My Ubuntu version:

```
# uname -a
Linux jenkins-lin 4.15.0-1037-gcp #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 3 06:28:59 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369932/bash-warning-shell-level-1000-too-high-resetting-to-1) SO question can help you.

Comment: @JeroenHeier thanks for the reply. I have already visited this link and it didn't help me because I only (trying to) run Sonar process, nothing else.